# How to add users in SonarQube using LDAP

Tags: ldap, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

Hi I've added the LDAP plugin to my new version of SonarQube (4.5.2) and I'm having difficulty adding a user to it.

I've checked the logs and it seems to linking up the SonarQube and checking it, but I'm struggling to find how I add a user from LDAP to SonarQube.

Answer (score 1):

When using the SonarQube LDAP plugin, you don't actually add users to SonarQube: they get added automatically once they log in for the first time.

And then, each time a users logs in again, the LDAP plugin synchronizes his/her information with SonarQube DB.

Answer (score 0):

The users will be added automatically in sonar with the LDAP configured groups when they login.

Attention: But the LDAP groups will not be added automatically. You will have to create them in sonar **before** the users will log in.

For details see [Sonar LDAP Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/LDAP+Plugin)

Comment: This is current code I have at the moment what am I missing...? 
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.authenticator.createUsers=true
ldap.url=ldap://10.20.0.220:3268
ldap.user.baseDn=dc=mydomain,dc=mydomain
ldap.bindDn=cn=sonar,cn=users,dc=mydomain,dc=mydomain
ldap.bindPassword=(mypassword)
ldap.user.baseDn=dc=mydomain,dc=mydomain
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName={sonar}))
ldap.authentication=simple
ldap.group.baseDn=ou=Groups,dc=mydomain,dc=mydomain ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=Sonar_Users)(memberUid={uid}))

Comment: Your "ldap.user.baseDn" is duplicate and perhaps the ou is missing. I have just the following configured, everything else is default.

sonar.security.realm = LDAP
sonar.authenticator.downcase = true

ldap.url = ldaps://ldap.internal.mycompany.tld
ldap.user.baseDn = ou=Users,dc=internal,dc=mycompany,dc=tld
ldap.group.baseDn=ou=Groups,dc=internal,dc=mycompany,dc=tld
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={uid}))